# How to Create a Dynamic Variable Name for an Array?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, combobox

I have "ComboBox1" with entries in it. Every time the user selects an entry, the following is triggered:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    call populate(ComboBox1.ListIndex)
End Sub
```

The function "populate" has the following:

```
Sub populate(index as integer)

    dim arr0, arr1, arr2 ...
        arr0 = Array(...)
        arr1 = Array(...)
        arr2 = Array(...)

    Do While x < Application.CountA("arr" + index)
        ...
    Loop

End Sub
```

I want to make **"arr" + index** dynamic so it calls the proper array based on the index recevied from the caller function. Can this be done?

Comment: Use an array to hold your arrays...

Comment: Based on the answer below, what is the syntax to call an element within the dynamic name? Example, arr(index).x where x = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub populate(index as integer)

    dim arr(0 to 2)
        arr(0) = Array(...)
        arr(1) = Array(...)
        arr(2) = Array(...)

    Do While x < Application.CountA(arr(index))
        ...
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: How would you call an element? Example, arr(index).x ??