# Autofilter array criteria

Tags: excel, vba

In excel VBA when applying an autofilter if the following works:

```
AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("Apples","Peaches"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Why when adding <> to denote NOT these values it brings up a "Run-time error '1004' Autofilter method or range class failed"

```
AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("<>Apples","<>Peaches"), Operator:=xlFilterValuesBest,
```

Is there something I am missing?

Thank you in advance
Best,
Nasos

Comment: In the range where the filter is applied there are other values like lemons, oranges etc

Comment: ~ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$6").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>*orange*" _
        , Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="<>*guava*"~ It works instead of Array

Comment: @skkakkar I have thought of that but the problem is I need to put this in a dynamic array. I have created a named range with the following  entries "<>apples", "<>Oranges", "<>Lemons" etc and depending on what the user selects it will add the respective options in the array. If I use the Criteria1 Criteria2 etc do you know if I make this dynamic?

Comment: I have just started learning this area and it will take me time to hone up my skills. You may find some related concepts in this post [How to Create a Dynamic Variable Name for an Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631761/how-to-create-a-dynamic-variable-name-for-an-array/31631780#)